# Magento 2 . Add custom success message on successful checkout

Tags: php, checkout, event-observer, magento-2.1.10

I am working on Magento version **2.1.10** and created an observer for event "***sales_order_place_after***", I need to show custom success message after successful checkout on checkout success page.

following is my current code:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Customsuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager )
    {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
        $this->_messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('This is a success message'));
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the success page and write your own success messages.
Why you creating event.

Go to your current theme

```
app\design\frontend\Renegade\default\Magento_Checkout\templates\success.phtml
```

You can changed success message that you want

Comment: This is OK.. but I have various conditions on which I need to show different custom messages. That is why i am creating event.

Comment: You can use various condition on success pages as well